# How to clone/copy data from local mongodb(localhost:27017) to remote mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created backend for one of my application using nodejs and mongodb. Now I wanted to clone/copy the whole database from my local mongodb to my remote mongodb.

I know mongodb provides db.copy and b.copyDatabase(), but it is deprecated since version 4.0 and I am using version 4.0. They are also saying that we can use mongodump and mongostore command but that doesn't work for my requirement.

1. Do we have any specific command for this?
2. I also wanted to do this in the nodejs. Is there anyway to achieve this?

please someone help me, this is very important for me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongodump and mongorestore on the command line.

For dumping your local mongodb:

```
mongodump --db you_db_name --collection your_collection_name
```

It will generate a dump folder with a list of json and bson files.

To restore to the remote mongodb:

```
mongorestore --host your_mongo_host --port your_mongo_port --username your_mongo_username --password your_mongo_password --collection your_collection_name --db your_db_name -- dump/
```

For more detail on the parameter of the command:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump

and

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ken. I tried mongodump but this will dump data into local folder but I wanted the data to be dumped into my remote mongo db.  I tried using this command:  "mongodump --port 27017 --uri  "mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0-6rknx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority". But mongodump command is not allowing both port and uri at a time.

Comment: Seem you are using Mongo Altas. They have a detail tutorial on backup and restore data with clusters. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/command-line-tools/#connect-with-mongorestore. Access the Command Line Tools Tab and follow the instructions and you will get the command line.

Comment: Wow, thanks Ken, the link you provided helped me . Yes I am using atlas. Now I am able to restore my data from my local mongo db to remote mongodb using mongodb commands.  Can you also help me how can I achieve the same using nodejs code.